# Issue with the pagination and redirecting to the top of the new page

Tags: reactjs, scroll, pagination, react-router, react-bootstrap

We have integrated the pagination to our website in one tutorial. I have a certain number of products on each page and there are multiple pages. When I scroll down on one page and when I hit the button, which redirects me to another page, then I am being redirected to the bottom of the new page, but I would need to be redirected to the top of that new page.

According to this link - https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/scroll-restoration - I should create a new component called ScrollToTop.js and then I should add the `<ScrollToTop />` tag to the App.js file, but when I do that, the issue persists.

ScrollToTop.js -

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

App.js -

```
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import ScrollToTop from "../components/ScrollToTop";

import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import ProductScreen from "./screens/ProductScreen";
import CartScreen from "./screens/CartScreen";
import LoginScreen from "./screens/LoginScreen";
import RegisterScreen from "./screens/RegisterScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "./screens/ProfileScreen";
import ShippingScreen from "./screens/ShippingScreen";
import PaymentScreen from "./screens/PaymentScreen";
import PlaceOrderScreen from "./screens/PlaceOrderScreen";
import OrderScreen from "./screens/OrderScreen";
import UserListScreen from "./screens/UserListScreen";
import UserEditScreen from "./screens/UserEditScreen";
import ProductListScreen from "./screens/ProductListScreen";
import ProductEditScreen from "./screens/ProductEditScreen";
import OrderListScreen from "./screens/OrderListScreen";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <Header />
      <main className="py-3">
        <Container>
          <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact />
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginScreen} />
          <Route path="/register" component={RegisterScreen} />
          <Route path="/profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
          <Route path="/shipping" component={ShippingScreen} />
          <Route path="/placeorder" component={PlaceOrderScreen} />
          <Route path="/order/:id" component={OrderScreen} />
          <Route path="/payment" component={PaymentScreen} />
          <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductScreen} />
          <Route path="/cart/:id?" component={CartScreen} />

          <Route path="/admin/userlist" component={UserListScreen} />
          <Route path="/admin/user/:id/edit" component={UserEditScreen} />

          <Route path="/admin/productlist" component={ProductListScreen} />
          <Route path="/admin/product/:id/edit" component={ProductEditScreen} />

          <Route path="/admin/orderlist" component={OrderListScreen} />
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Paginate.js -

```
import React from 'react'
import { Pagination } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap'

function Paginate({pages, page, keyword= '', isAdmin=false }) {
                                          
    if(keyword){
        keyword = keyword.split('?keyword=')[1].split('&')[0]
    }                      
                             
    return (pages > 1 && (
        <Pagination>
            {[...Array(pages).keys()].map((x) => (
                 <LinkContainer
                 key={x + 1}
                 to={!isAdmin ? 
                     `/?keyword=${keyword}&page=${x + 1}`
                     : `/admin/productlist/?keyword=${keyword}&page=${x + 1}`
                 }
                 >                          
                       <Pagination.Item active={x + 1 ===page}>{x + 1}</Pagination.Item>
                 </LinkContainer>              
            ))}
        </Pagination>
    )                            
        
    )
}

export default Paginate
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by creating the ScrollToTop.js component (inside the components folder) as the mentioned link suggests, but instead of adding the  tag to the App.js file, it is necessary to add it to the Paginate.js component. That can be done in 2 steps.

(Both of the following adjustments can be removed from the App.js file)

1. Import the ScrollToTop.js component to the Paginate.js file like this -

```
import ScrollToTop from "./ScrollToTop";
```

or like this -

```
import ScrollToTop from "../components/ScrollToTop";
```

2. Add the `<ScrollToTop />` tag to the Paginate.js component as shown below - (add it right below the `<Pagination>` tag)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Pagination } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap'
import ScrollToTop from "../components/ScrollToTop";

function Paginate({pages, page, keyword= '', isAdmin=false }) {

    if(keyword){
        keyword = keyword.split('?keyword=')[1].split('&')[0]
    }                      

    return (pages > 1 && (
        <Pagination>
            <ScrollToTop />
            {[...Array(pages).keys()].map((x) => (
                 <LinkContainer
                 key={x + 1}
                 to={!isAdmin ? 
                     `/?keyword=${keyword}&page=${x + 1}`
                     : `/admin/productlist/?keyword=${keyword}&page=${x + 1}`
                 }
                 >                          
                       <Pagination.Item active={x + 1 ===page}>{x + 1}</Pagination.Item>
                 </LinkContainer>              
            ))}
        </Pagination>
    )                            

    )
}

export default Paginate
```